# Take action when system clock changes minute?

Tags: android, runnable

My Android app has a `TextView` telling the user the data age ("13 minute ago"). I currently update this every second using a `Runnable` to catch when the minute changes with a `notifyDataSetChanged()` to my adapter. But this is causing garbage collection every second...

Is there another method to trigger a `TextView` update (or take general action) when the system clock changes minute without checking every second for such a change?

Comment: Why dont you simply spread out your counter / timer to trigger every 30 seconds or so (instead of 1), the most you will ever be behind is 29 seconds.

Comment: It crossed my mind. I guess I don't like it when the system clock (visible to the user) flips a minute and the age in the ListView does not. Picky, I know...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already set up a Runnable and callback, use modulo to calculate when the next update should happen:

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 
        DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS - System.currentTimeMillis % DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
```

This will run the callback when the next minute occurs whether it is 59, 30, or 1 second(s) away.  As a note, if the Runnable only updates one TextView don;t forget to switch to `DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS` when the event is an hour old, no sense updating "1 hour ago" every minute.

You may find methods like [`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long%29) useful for creating the "x minutes ago" strings.

Comment: Holy crap, what a great solution! Thanks so much.

Comment: I like this. The handler should fire when the minute elapses though:

DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS - System.currentTimeMillis() % DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS

Answer (score 5):

While Sam's answer is perfectly good, I'm just adding this because it fits the question so perfectly. There is actually a broadcast sent by the system every minute when the clock changes. It is `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK` and you can only receive it using a `BroadCastReceiver` that was registered manually in your code, not through the manifest. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED).

Comment: That's actually very handy too. I'll have to take a closer look at it. Thanks!

Comment: This is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934625/android-listener-that-detects-minute-changing-in-the-clock/44192366

Answer (score 0):

User the Timer object with fixed period.

The methods take a TimerTask object.

See the [Timer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) from google

REMEMEBER to cancel the timer when stopping the activity

Answer (score 0):

There is prettier solution for this besides Sam's great answer.

Make use of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html to find the time span and register for `android.intent.action.TIME_TICK` where you'll be updating the time in the listview.

Here is another same question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934625/android-listener-that-detects-minute-changing-in-the-clock/44192366)